# Как перенести слова из одного массива в другой

Tags: c

Вот, данная программа проходится по тексту из test.txt, записывает все слова в переменную istr. Хочу чтобы из переменной в istr слова передавались в strok[words], и чтобы каждое слово было под своим адресом.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LEN 100

int main(void) {
    int words=0;
    char str[LEN];
    char* istr;
    char** strok=calloc(100,1);
    //char *istr1;

    FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");;
    printf("\nТекст файла\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        istr = fgets(str, LEN, fp);
        //printf("%s", istr);
        for ( istr = strtok(str, " .\t\n"); istr; istr = strtok(NULL, " .\t\n")) {
          char* st=malloc(20);
          strok[words]=calloc(20,1);
          sscanf(istr, "%s", strok[words]);
          sprintf(istr, "%s", strok[words]);//пытался и в sscanf и тут, не выходит
          words++;
            printf("%p\n", &strok[words]);
            printf("%s\n", strok[words]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char **words = NULL; //указатель на массив слов
int count = 0; //количество слов

FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); //определяем размер файла и выделяем буфер нужного размера
int size = ftell(file);
char *buffer = malloc(size + 1);
rewind(file); //считываем текст и добавляем завершающий \0 в конце
buffer[fread(buffer, 1, size, file)] = '\0'; //* (смотри примечание ниже)
fclose(file);

char *delimiters = " .,!'';?:-()+-*%@&<>/\\\"\n\t"; //символы-разделители

char *pword = strtok(buffer, delimiters);
while (pword) {
    words = realloc(words, (count + 1) * sizeof(char*)); //добавляем новый элемент в массив
    words[count++] = pword; //записываем в него указатель на слово и увеличиваем счётчик
    pword = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
}

//вывод:
int i;
printf("файл содержит %d слов:\n", count);
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) puts(words[i]);
```

*: *когда файл открыт в текстовом режиме `fread` может выполнять некоторые преобразования (например заменять `\r\n` на `\n`), поэтому определяя позицию завершающего `\0` следует ориентироваться не на размер файла, а на количество записанных в буфер символов (которое возвращает `fread`).*

Comment: При таком подходе можно также сразу выделить достаточно памяти под вектор указателей на слова и не делать `realloc` для каждого слова. Очевидно, что максимальное количество слов в файле будет равно его размеру, деленному на 2 + 1

Comment: Возник вопрос, что будет, если я не добавлю завершающий '\0'?, а просто сделаю fread, без добавления последнему элементу '\0'?

Comment: @ЯрославЗахаров, тогда `strtok` не будет знать где заканчивается текст, выйдет за его границы и будет продолжать пока не наткнётся на 0 или недоступную память.

Comment: Спасибо, но можно узнать, что за переменная is_first? Для чего она? И можно ли вывод каким нибудь образом рассортировать? Чтобы выводил частоту от большего к меньшему

Comment: Здравствуйте, почему вы удалил часть, где находились повторения слов с переменными is_first и wcnt? Просто хотел узнать как работает эта функция

Comment: Я ничего не удалял, т. к. в моём ответе никогда не было никаких is_first и wcnt. Единственная правка, которую я делал - добавил примечание про завершающий \0.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью функции `fscanf()` проще считывать данные с файлов:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 100     //количество строк
#define LEN_STR 32  //количество символов в строке


int isMarks(char ch){
    return (ch=='.' || ch==',' || ch==';' || ch=='?' || ch=='!') ? 1 : 0;
}

int main(void) {

    int words = 0;  //кол-во слов на запись

    char strok[LEN][LEN_STR];

    FILE* fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
        //проверка файла
    if(fp==NULL){ printf("Error!\n"); return 0; }

    printf("\nТекст файла\n\n");

    while (!feof(fp))
        fscanf(fp,"%s", strok[words++]);    //чтение в массив


    fclose(fp);

    //удаление знаков синтаксиса
    for(int i=0; i<words; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<LEN_STR; j++)
            if(isMarks(strok[i][j])){
                strok[i][j] = '\0';
            }


    //вывод результата
    for(int i=0; i<words-1; i++)
        printf("%d. %s\n",(i+1), strok[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, что помогли, но так он записывает все что видит, знаки препинания и т д, а хотелось бы только слова.

Comment: Дальше можно сортировать сами элементы массива на наличие знаков препинания. scanf() помогает отделить слова и поместить их в массив.

Comment: Вот самая простая форма удаления знаков препинания в строках (с учётом того, что они поставлены в конце слов). Для парсинга строк лучше подходит библиотека из C++ <regex> для [регулярных выражений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 0):

Для начала,  идиоматическое чтение файла по строкам пишется вот так:

```
while (fgets(str, LEN, fp)) { 
   ... 
}
```

Теперь, в цикле `for` с вызовом `strtok()` вы получаете искомые слова, завершающиеся нулем (из каких символов они состоят, зависит от набора разделителей, который вы передаете в `strtok()`). Внутри цикла у вас на очередное слово указывает переменная `istr`.

Для достижения желаемой цели вам остается скопировать очередное слово в новый элемент массива.

Для этого 
надо убедиться, что текущий размер массива достаточен (если нет, расширим массив).  Допустим, в начале вы добавите переменную, содержащую размер массива

```
size_t s_size = 10;
```

а затем создадите массив (как вы это и делаете)

```
char **strok = malloc(s_size * sizeof(char *));
```

Тогда перемещение очередного слова (точнее его копии в динамической памяти) в массив можно сделать так

```
if (words == s_size) {
   s_size *= 2; 
   strok = realloc(strok, s_size * sizeof(char *));
}
strok[words++] = strdup(istr);
```

Вот, собственно, и вся программа.
(между прочим, вы и сами практически ее написали, только немного запутались в ... -))

Конечно, после `realloc` надо бы проверить, что память реально выделена и аккуратно завершиться, если памяти больше нет. После `while (fgets(...))` можно проверить, не завершилось ли чтение строки с ошибкой (функция `ferror()`), возможен дополнительный анализ символов в слове и его редактирование и т.д. и т.п.